# When testing end to end integration testing using TestCafe how to manage waiting for email receipt

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

With system under test, when adding a new user their initial password is emailed to them.

I could split my test into multiple sections with manual intervention but this is less than ideal.

Appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed using TestCafe as I am sure others have encountered this as well.

Comment: I don't know testcafe specifically, but in similar cases I've either: 1. Made "email" a call to a configurable webhook and stubbed it out; or 2. Used an SMTP server as sender or recipient that exposes an API for checking the mailbox (mailhog locally, MailGun as a hosted service, ...).

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run full integration test with real email server, then you can use libraries like "mail-receive" to connect to this server and verify the email.

You can also run your backend/server logic in mock mode, and then verify the mock, that the send event happened, by calling some test-specific rest endpoint from your TestCafe test.

Alternatively, you could also use something like "smtp-receiver" to start your own email-server-mock in nodejs context, and receive event upon email arrival. However you will need to configure your app server/backend to point to this mocked email server.

Comment: Several good options, mail-receive and smtp-receiver sound like potential options. Now I have direction.

Comment: [This example](https://dev-tester.com/email-testing-made-simple-with-testcafe-and-mailosaur/) may be also useful.